# Changing server.js when deploying

Tags: node.js, reactjs, deployment, nodemailer, react-forms

I know almost nothing about NodeJS, but I am building my Portfolio website in React and I wanna include a Contact Form. I use `nodemailer` but there is something I don't know:
I have my `server.js` file that is listening to port 5000 (`app.listen(5000, () => console.log("Server: Running"));`).
Well, I have this `handleSubmit` function that is running when the user submits the form:

```
const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  setButtonText("Sending...");
  let response = await fetch("http://localhost:5000/contact", {
    method: "POST",
    headers: { "Content-Type": "Application/json;charset=utf-8" },
    body: JSON.stringify(formDetails),
  });
  setButtonText("Send");
  let result = response.json();
  setFormDetails(formInitialDetails);
  if (result.code === 200)
    setStatus({ succes: true, message: "Message sebt successfully" });
  else setStatus({ succes: false, message: "Something went wrong!" });
}
```

And the form: `<form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>...</form>`

Now my question is: If my `handleSubmit` function is listening at `http://localhost:5000/contact` what am I supposed to do (to change) in order to make this React App work as I expect when I deploy it. I mean: if I deploy this with GitHub Pages or Netlify the URL will be different than `http://localhost:5000/contact`, right? So what I have to do before I deploy it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use environment variable instead of let your url in your code.
Like:

```
const response = await fetch(process.env.serverUrl, {
    method: "POST",
    headers: { "Content-Type": "Application/json;charset=utf-8" },
    body: JSON.stringify(formDetails),
  });
```

And then set your environment variable `serverUrl` in Github Pages (see how [here](https://docs.github.com/en/enterprise-cloud@latest/actions/learn-github-actions/variables#creating-configuration-variables-for-a-repository))

Answer (score 1):

you should add the url dynamically depending of the original url of the page, you can do that with with javascript like, in your case try this:

```
let response = await fetch(`${window.location.protocol}//${window.location.host}/contact`, {
    method: "POST",
    headers: { "Content-Type": "Application/json;charset=utf-8" },
    body: JSON.stringify(formDetails),
  });
```

Comment: Well thanks a lot man! I should've think about this... Ups!:))